# How can I work around a possible "wait_for" event error with my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have an event waiting for a reaction under a message. But if the bot should fail once this event is dropped and if you then click on the reaction there is no reaction from the bot, because he can not capture this reaction. Is there an alternative how to get the bot to continue anyway?
I don't like to work with a `timeout` event or `asyncio.sleep`, because the input should come from the user. Is this possible?
My code so far without workaround:

```py
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=43200)
                while user == self.bot.user:
                    reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=43200)
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "⏯":
                    await ctx.send("**Your next question will appear in `6` seconds.**", delete_after=5)
                    await intense.delete()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("**Really?! I though `12 hours` would be enough..."
                               "Your next question will come in about `6` seconds.**", delete_after=5)

            await asyncio.sleep(6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I've added two examples and tweaked up existing code to make it a little more cleaner. It cannot fail unless the message that the bot was adding to was deleted, otherwise it would work. I also added a check function just to help, but you can change that to whatever you want. Included a true loop, so it would keep waiting for an input.

```
message = await ctx.send("Test reactions")

back = '⬅️'
forward= '⏯'

await message.add_reaction(back)
await message.add_reaction(forward)

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in [back, forward]
        
        member = ctx.author
        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)

                if str(reaction.emoji) == back:
                    await ctx.send('Going back')

                if str(reaction.emoji) == forward:
                    await ctx.send('Going forward')
```

Your other solution is just to use `on_reaction_add` event, but I wouldn't recommend, unless your bot is small and no one minds if a message always gets send if they sent an emoji you put in your code.

It's by far a much easier approach but may not expect the best results compared to the `wait_for` But hope this helps too.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

        if reaction.emoji == '⬅️':
            await ctx.send('Going back')


        if reaction.emoji == '⏯':
            await ctx.send('Going back')
```

The problem with this, is it's always active and waiting for those reactions to be added, it can cause intermittent slowdown of the bot, or people could react to the emojis by accident and mess up the command because they shouldn't be able to use these commands unless the original command has been invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=raw_reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) should work in this context. Eveytime a user will interact with the message reaction it causes an event

Comment: But doesn't this event rely on a fixed message and a fixed channel to get this reaction?